# JMeter - generation of timeslots and saving to a file

Tags: java, file, date, jmeter, edit

I have a manually edited file with timeslots (StartDate, EndDate) for the next day with 10 minutes sliding shift and the following structure:

```
StartDate,EndDate
2021-05-07T07:00:00,2021-05-07T07:10:00
2021-05-07T07:10:00,2021-05-07T07:20:00
2021-05-07T07:20:00,2021-05-07T07:30:00
2021-05-07T07:30:00,2021-05-07T07:40:00
2021-05-07T07:40:00,2021-05-07T07:50:00
2021-05-07T07:50:00,2021-05-07T08:00:00
2021-05-07T08:00:00,2021-05-07T08:10:00
2021-05-07T08:10:00,2021-05-07T08:20:00
...
(etc.)
```

Currently, I update and replace date in a file to the next day each day manually.

What is the best way in `JMeter (Java)` to automate timeslots updates/data generation and write/replace outdated date with a new date in file?

Answer (score 1):

It's not very clear what you're trying to achieve, if you have arbitrary dates and times written in some file and would like to change the dates to "tomorrow" on the fly - it can be achieved quite easily using [__groovy() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__groovy), something like:

```
${__groovy(java.time.LocalDateTime.parse(vars.get('StartDate')).plusDays(java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(java.time.LocalDateTime.parse(vars.get('StartDate'))\, java.time.LocalDateTime.now()) + 1).format(java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME),)}
```

Demo:

[image]

More information:

- [Introduction to the Java 8 Date/Time API](https://www.baeldung.com/java-8-date-time-intro)
- [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)

Comment: @Dmitry T, the goal is to replace only date in file with tomorrow or next Monday date and keep timeslots time.